# Truffle console doesn't work :Unexpected error: Cannot provision contracts while instantiating the console

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc

when I run truffle compile, truffle migrate successfully and then truffle console gives me the following error. 
strong text

```
**Enexpected error: Cannot provision contracts while instantiating the console.
Error: Cannot parse .DS_Store: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/lib/repl.js:69:27
    at tryToString (fs.js:447:3)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:434:12)
truffle(development)> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at TruffleInterpreter.resetContractsInConsoleContext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/lib/repl.js:95:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/lib/repl.js:44:12**
```

UPDATE: I solved this problem by pulling a fresh copy of my code from github. And then in my new project directory, I re did npm install. Hope this is helpful

Comment: No 100% sure but I think you have the MacOS metadata folder file [`.DS_Store`] somewhere it shouldn't be. Try to find in one of the truffle folders (build, contract, migration or test). Otherwise, it's always good to give OS and software versions.

Comment: hi @gjeanmart I have no such file. there is some other people having the same problem. Maybe its my version of truffle. maybe I need to wait for a new version to be released. Is there a way to downgrade my truffle?

Answer (score 6):

`.DS_Store` is [a hidden file created by macOS operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store). Operating system may automatically create this file under various circumstances. I assume that Truffle has a bug that instead of reading the specific files produced by a `truffle compile` it tries to read all files in the configured directory.

Truffle tries to read compiler outputted [JSON](http://json.org/) format files. Naturally `.DS_Store` is not a file of a such a format making `truffle` to crash.

The correct course of action here is to

- Delete `.DS_Store` file or makes sure `truffle compile` output goes into a clean directory. `.DS_Store` might not be visible in Finder listing, as its a special file, so it is better to delete with from the command line with `ls -la` and `rm` commands.
- File a bug against [truffle](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle/issues/)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It looks like the right answer. Would it not be better to comment if you feel it's not?

Answer (score 2):

Do not pull your code again from GH.

Do not reinstall npm.

**Delete build/contracts directory**. This is not dangerous because it gets recreated during compilation.

Comment: This worked, probably the best option assuming you have not already deployed to testnet/mainnet.

Answer (score 1):

Execute

```
find . -name ".DS_Store" -delete
```

Before running

```
truffle console
```

(Problem still exists in Truffle v4.1.6 (core: 4.1.6))

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all you input. I fixed the problem by asking the main developers of truffle. The told me to npm install again in the new directory. It works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I fixed it by deleting all the .DS_Store files in all the truffle directories. Below is what I did, it fixed my problem.

```
    Mac-sashi:dapp-experiments sashi$ ls -a
    .           app         package-lock.json
    ..          box-img-lg.png      package.json
    .DS_Store       box-img-sm.png      test
    .babelrc        build           truffle-box.json
    .eslintignore       contracts       truffle.js
    .eslintrc       index.html      webpack.config.js
    .gitignore      migrations
    README.md       node_modules
    Mac-sashi:dapp-experiments sashi$ rm app/.DS_Store 
    Mac-sashi:dapp-experiments sashi$ rm .DS_Store 
    Mac-sashi:dapp-experiments sashi$ rm test/.DS_Store 
    Mac-sashi:dapp-experiments sashi$ rm build/.DS_Store 
    Mac-sashi:dapp-experiments sashi$ rm contracts/.DS_Store 
    Mac-sashi:dapp-experiments sashi$ rm migrations/.DS_Store 
    Mac-sashi:dapp-experiments sashi$ rm node_modules/.DS_Store
```

Edit:I realized that everytime the directory is opened using finder, MacOs will generate .DS_Store file in the directory. So better doo all the operations using terminal.

Comment: I realized that everytime the directory is opened using finder, MacOs will generate .DS_Store file in the directory. So better doo all the operations using terminal.